# Collection of Generic Lists

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a function which needs to go through a class' types and identify a specific type.  If I find that type, I want to cast it to the type that I know it is.  But in the code below, the following case is failing:

```
 BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject> obj = pi.GetValue(item, null) as BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>;
```

Here is the code.  Basically, I am making an iterator which returns certain properties.  Why can't I cast?

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in item.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  if (pi.PropertyType.BaseType == null) continue; // skip interfaces
  if (!pi.PropertyType.BaseType.IsGenericType) continue;  // only interested in childlists

  Type[] types = pi.PropertyType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments();
  // is my generic argument derived from baseObject?
  if (typeof(BaseTableObject).IsAssignableFrom(types[0]))
  {
    // this is a child we want
    log.Info(types[0].Name);
    BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject> obj = pi.GetValue(item, null) as BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>;
    yield return obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you add `if (pi.GetValue(item, null) is BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>)` before you cast? Are you sure `pi.GetValue` returns object of type collection or `BaseTableObject`?

Comment: Indeed the IS test fails.  The thing I am passing in (the item) is declared as:  BaseTableObjectList<ABaseTableObjectType>

Comment: I would put a breakpoint there and use immediate window (ctrl+alt+i) and see what exactly `pi.GetValue` is.

Comment: Specifically, the item is defined as: CompanyList : BaseTableObjectList<Company>   On the breakpoint, the type shows up as CompanyList.  But shouldn't that BE a BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>?  Since Company IS as BaseTableObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have I think is one of covariance, which only applies to interfaces.  If you had a `IBaseTableObjectList<out T> where T : BaseTableObject` the cast wouldn't fail.  Covariance for generics is only supported on delegates and interfaces not on base classes:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

> In C#, variance is supported in the following scenarios:
>
> - Covariance in arrays (since C# 1.0)
> - Covariance and contravariance in delegates, also known as “method group variance” (since C# 2.0)
> - Variance for **generic type parameters in interfaces** and delegates (since C# 4.0)

This is essentially the same problem is assigning a `List<string>` to an `IEnumerable<object>` which is one of the examples in the linked article.

Comment: This does not seem any different that the code I have, just a shorter way to get to it.

Comment: Ah yeah I misunderstood your question, see my ammended answer.  I think the answer here is to try using an interface where you can employ variance.

Comment: I worked around it by changing the definition of the BaseTableObjectList to:  public abstract class BaseTableObjectList : System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string,object>   So I did away with generics here.  The rest of the code is not affected.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `pi.GetValue(item, null).GetType()` is actually the type you want to cast to. It seems like it returns `BaseTableObject` instead `BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>`

If your class `Company : BaseTableObject` and your `CompanyList : BaseTableObjectList<Company>` then your result can be cast to `BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>` by using `CompanyList.Cast<BaseTableObject>()`

Edit2: From your comments, I think the following code will do the work.

```
BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject> obj = new BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>((pi.GetValue(item, null) as System.Collections.IEnumerable).Cast<BaseTableObject>());
```

Comment: The type I get from that is CompanyList, which is defined as  BaseTableObjectList<Company>

Comment: So you can cast it as both types `CompanyList` or `BaseTableObjectList<Company>`. But, if Company inherits BaseTableObject, then you can't cast it to `BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>` and I think this is what you are trying to do. If that's the case, see my answer.

Comment: A caveat to this:  my method cannot know about the type "CompanyList", only about the BaseTableObject and BaseTableObjectList

Comment: So you are taking it to the next level :)
Edited my answer, you can cast to IEnumarable.

Comment: Well that compiles at least, and seems closer.  But obj still winds up completely empty.  pi.GetValue is of type CompanyList, which I would expect to be compatible with BaseTableObjectList<BaseTableObject>  but perhaps I am mixing generics and inheritance.

Comment: Empty or null? Perhaps there are no elements in the collection? Can you use the immediate window and see if `(pi.GetValue(item, null) as CompanyList).Count` has any elements?

Comment: Can you post the exact class signuatures for CompanyList, BaseTableObject, BaseTableObjectList<T> etc? Just the class declarations. If `pi.GetValue` returns CompanyList, casting it to IEnumarable (non-generic) and then calling .Cast<object>().ToList() should really be non-empty if your CompanyList has any items in the collection.